# How can I resolve the issue where pressing J in VSCode's Vim extension "waits for the second chord" even after a fresh installation?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

When pressing J, it "waits for the second chord".

https://share.cleanshot.com/lLsKvvJ0

The extension is freshly installed for the fifth time and it still occurs; I checked the `~/.vscode/extensions` directory after uninstalling to see if there were still some cached settings, but there appeared to not be any. I used to bind `j + k` in insert mode to switch to editing mode, but removed it later; this issue has happened ever since. I suspect there's some issue with settings, but it's still weird that it happens after re-installation.

Here are my extensions in VSCode:
[image]

`Vim: Command Line Mode Key Bindings`

```
{
  "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
  "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",

  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
  },
  "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
  "audioCues.lineHasError": "off",
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Dracula",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "vim.overrideCopy": false,
  "vim.commandLineModeKeyBindings": [ // this is where I previously configured the keybinds and later removed them
  
  ],
  "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [], // or it might have been here...
  "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [],
  "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
  "vim.camelCaseMotion.enable": true,
  "vim.commandLineModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [],
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.fontSize": 13,
  "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF"
}
```

P.S I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.4.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the keybinding I had previously assigned to 'j' was still there; I had to go through the `.JSON` file itself, because the UI did not show it.

Here's the GitHub issue for reference: